# Highchart tooltip customization

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using highcharts and i would like to customize tooltip.
My tooltip should show the reqName and reqVersion,but currently the tooltip is showing all the values of the 'tipValue' array.

When i hover over the column it shows me tooltip on each column as (1.1,1.0,1.2,1.2)

```
where as I would like the tooltip to show version 
1.1 for column tpReq 
1.0 for column opReq
1.2 for column Rex
1.2 for column tpReq

My xVaue is an array of ['tpReq','opReq','Rex','tpReq']
My yValue is an array of [5,8,5,1]
My tipValue is an array of ['1.1','1.0','1.2','1.2']
```

Here is my function to draw the highcharts

```
function drawchar(myXAxis,myYAxis,myTooltip)
{
   var xValue = JSON.parse(XAxis);
   var yValue = JSON.parse(YAxis);
   var tipValue = JSON.parse(myTooltip);

   var reqTypeChart = new HighCharts.Chart ({
   ...
   ...
     xAxis: {
                    categories: xValue,
                    title: { 'My Requests'
                        text: null
                    },

                },
                ....
                series: [{
                    name: 'Status',
                    data: yValue
                }],
                legend: { enabled: false },
               tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<b>' + this.xValue + '</b><br/>' +
                                'IssueCount: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.yValue, 0) + '</b><br/>' + 
                                'AppVersion: ' + tipValue ;
                    }

...
});
}
```

Comment: In tooltip you need to referer to particular index of array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
function drawchar(myXAxis, myYAxis, myTooltip) {
    var xValue = JSON.parse(myXAxis);
    var yValue = JSON.parse(myYAxis);
    var tipValue = JSON.parse(myTooltip);

    var data = [];
    $.each(xValue, function (index, val) {
        var tempObj = {
            x: val,
            y: yValue[index],
            tipValue: tipValue[index]
        }
        data.push(tempObj);

    });

    // **UPDATED ** 

   data.sort(function(a, b){ 
      if(a.x < b.x) return -1; 
      if(a.x > b.x) return 1; return 0; 
   })

    var reqTypeChart = new HighCharts.Chart({

        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'My Requests'
            }
        },
        series: [
            {
                name: 'Status',
                data: data
            }
        ],
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.point.x + '</b><br/>' +
                    'IssueCount: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.y, 0) + '</b><br/>' +
                    'AppVersion: ' + this.point.tipValue;
            }


        }
    });
}
```

Combine all three values into one array of objects and set that array as data source in series of highchart api. You'll get passed object inside formatter method of tooltip wrapped into this.point object.

Comment: If I use this approach, I get a straight line, no columns. Also I would like my xAxis to show the 'Request Name' which is in xValue.

Comment: try to sort data array by x alphabetically before use. this should solve issue of straight line.

data.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a.x < b.x) return -1;
    if(a.x > b.x) return 1;
    return 0;
})

Comment: for x axis title put value 'Request Name' of key text xAsix>title

Comment: I am still getting straight line. Also I did not mean 'Request Name' as title, I meant  xAxis: {
                categories: xValue,
                title: {
                    text: null
                },

Comment: Are u passing categories right now? See, we have passed values of x axis inside series array so no need to pass categories as xValue inside xaxis.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by changing the tooltip formater. So first find the index of xValue and find the corresponding tooltip value from tipValue array.

```
formatter: function () {
          var index = xValue.indexOf(this.xValue);
          var tip = tipValue[index];
          return '<b>' + this.xValue + '</b><br/>' +
      'IssueCount: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.yValue, 0) + '</b><br/>' + 
      'AppVersion: ' + tip ;
```